# GetAsynchKeyState for Ctrl+B? How?

Tags: c#, c++

I am using

```
public static bool IsKeyPushedDown(Keys vKey)
{
   return 0 != (GetAsyncKeyState((int)vKey) & 0x8000);
}
```

but I don't know how to combine 2 keys.

Comment: You could trap WM_KEYDOWN, compare the incoming key against 'B' and then check the state of the CTRL key using GetAsyncKeyState (like you are now).

Or, you could use an accelerator table: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153544(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Generally speaking, `GetAsyncKeyState` is a bad idea since it ignores things like typeahead. You should use your thread's current key state, not the async key state. And ideally you would just listen for `WM_CHAR` of 2 (the ASCII code for Ctrl+B). That would allow you to work with virtual keyboards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `if (IsKeyPushedDown('B') && IskeyPushedDown(VK_CONTROL))` perhaps?

As others have stated in comments using the events WM_KEYDOWN or WM_CHAR to check for "someone pressed a key" is indeed the "right" solution for "I want to call a function when someone presses a key". However, you specifically asked "I'm using ..some code.. I don't know how to combine 2 keys", which the above is definitely the correct answer to.

Comment: Yes, this should work. However, user2026052, you should keep in mind that this condition will be true as long as CTRL + B is held down, since GetAsyncKeyState gets the key's current state, not just when the keys are first pressed. You'll likely have to maintain the key states yourself if you only want to capture the first instance of CTRL + B being pressed (so you'd only handle cases where B was previously unpressed and is now being pressed).

Comment: if ((IsKeyPushedDown(Keys.B) && IsKeyPushedDown(Keys.Control)))
Wont work, looks like that func cant be done without making additional thread

Comment: "Wont work" in this case means what? Please explain [preferrably in the original question] what you are trying to achieve. It's starting to sound like you are asking an XY question - you want to do X, you have the idea to achieve that is by using Y, so you ask how to do Y. Unfortunately for us, we don't know what X is, so can't give appropriate advice as to how you best go about solving your problem. I've answered the Y question [I believe correctly].

Comment: X: I want to call function by pressing for example: Ctrl+B
Y as MaybeGoodSolution: GetAsynchKeyState
Z as Problem: Y wont catch pair of keys, at least for me - I can catch only one. I cant make linebrak...

Comment: I've edited my answer. If you'd rather that I delete the answer because I answered your ACTUAL question, then fine. Please say so!